# Add Google Assistant routines from my app

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to develop an interactive "allspeech-based" application and I have found some troubles.

I would be able to do every task of my app without the touch input, only the voice one.

So, my idea was to use Google Assitant to open my app, and then execute tasks with Activities "allspeech-based". My only problem is open my app with a custom phrase like "Hello myApp".

I've noticed that Google only permit to define  in Manifest in which developer can set predefined method like SEARCH_ACTION (I have to say "Serch cats in myAPP..."), ... and not custom action!

Then I had an idea: to resolve this I can define a new routine in my Google Assistant where Command is "Hello myApp" and action is "Open myApp", and it works!

But I don't want to force my users to add a new tourine in their Assistant, I want to do it from my app automatically at the first opening of my app (throught an Intent and a startActivity or something similar idk).

**My question is**: How can I do? Which Intent I have to invoke? With which extras? Is it possible?

Please answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such intent which can directly create a new routine.

Comment: Ok., and there is any other way to open my app in a specific activity using a custom phrase? Because i know about the possiblity of using <action> tags in Android Manifest (e.g: <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_ALARM" />) but this means use predefined phrase like "set alarm at...".

Comment: There's no such capability in the way that you'd want it to be done.

Comment: It's simple: I have an app named "Drinking water". From the google assistant of my phone i would be able to say: "Ok google, i'm thirsty" to open my app. In other words I would set somewhere in my app that the String "I'm thirsty" invoked in Google Assistant opens my app in a defined Activity (same functioning of deep linking but with Ok Google)

Comment: There's no capability to link strings you define to the Assistant through your app.